# Ansible: append list and dict

Tags: ansible

I have the following:

`containers:
  - name: "c1"
    devices:
      https: { listen: "tcp:{{l}}:443", connect: "tcp:{{c}}:443", bind:"host", type: "proxy" }
    proxy: 
      - { name: http, dst: 80, nxt: 80, proto: tcp }
      - { name: ssh, dst: 1200, nxt: 22, proto: tcp }
  - name: "c2"
    devices:
      pg : { listen: "tcp:{{ lip }}:8085", connect: "tcp:{{ cip }}:8085", bind: "host", type: "proxy" }`

And I'd like to merge the devices and proxy in such a manner, that i.e. c1's devices will contain

`https: {listen: "tcp:{{l}}:443", connect: "tcp:{{c}}:443", bind:"host", type: "proxy"}
http: {listen: "tcp:{{l}}:80", connect: "tcp:{{c}}:80", bind:"host", type: "proxy" }
ssh: {listen: "tcp:{{l}}:1200", connect: "tcp:{{c}}:22", bind:"host", type: "proxy" }`

where the two new items are just reordered values of the proxy. I tried to decompose this into several steps, but I keep hitting errors or typos. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Got it! See below.

Comment: Getting closer (see edit)

Comment: You have already with your edit, what is missing now?

Comment: Almost there, merging two dicts stops things.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I split this into two files, outer and inner. The outer goes as this:

`- include_tasks: inner.yml
  with_items: "{{ containers }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item`

the inner as this: https://gist.github.com/killua-eu/f81af4a84e9cc1394d028a9b193380e7